# hibernate query list: empty or null?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, null, jpql

If I have method which use Hibernate, like this:

```
public <T> T typedQuery(Query q, Class<T> type) {
    List<T> results = q.list();

    //result will be null or empty List ?
}
```

If query won't get any record from table, `result` will be `null` or empty List?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It will return an empty list, if there are no results. [Relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3599343/4074715)